# Is there an example of a java.net.http request with URI that does not refer to http(s)?

Tags: java

The [java.net.http](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html) package takes URI to build a request. Is there an example of a working request URI that does not refer to http(s)?

For example:

```
HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .uri(new URI("https://postman-echo.com/get"))
```

Why does the builder take `URI` rather than a `URL`? Are there any working examples that demonstrate the usefulness of `URI` in this context, over `URL`?

Comment: Websockets, for example.

Comment: I see! So a websocket connection is described using a URI instead of a URL - why is this exactly?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. I think URIs being more general  might make the API future proof and uniform once they decide to use some URIs that are not URLs, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Right. The websocket API seems to be a different one:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/WebSocket.Builder.html

but uniformity may be a good reason.

Comment: I can think of two other potential reasons, the first being convenience: The URI class has a static factory `create` that does not require one to handle a checked exception. The second reason is that the URL class has a problem that not many people know about: When using the `equals` method of the URL class, that method does a DNS lookup.